# Qual é a diferença entre "caracter" e "caráter"?

Tags: ortografia, significado, uso-de-palavras

No inglês, ambas palavras se traduzem a:

> character

Qual seria a diferença entre essas duas palavras?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- "Caráter" refere-se a [um conjunto de características de personalidade de uma pessoa ou de um grupo de pessoas](http://www.significados.com.br/carater/);
- "Carácter" ([ou ainda "caractere", apenas no Brasil](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/745)), refere-se a [um sinal gráfico não composto por sinais menores, como como uma letra do alfabeto, um algarismo, um sinal de pontuação ou um símbolo utilizado na imprensa ou na informática](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/caractere).

Comment: Não encontro caráter no dicionário. Explorar isso melhoraria esta resposta.

Comment: [Está aqui o caráter](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/car%C3%A1ter)

Comment: Isto não me parece correto... Como eu [comentei](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/#comment5632_1208) noutra resposta, _caractere_ é [desaconselhado em Portugal](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/745), e apesar de válido no Brasil, é [considerado informal](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?palavra=caractere). Além disso, a forma _caracter_ não é válido em nenhum dos países, apesar de muito propagada por desconhecedores do singular correto.

Comment: Eu disse "informal" por engano meu, o dicionário parece estar a referir-se ao âmbito da Informática. Mas o meu objetivo principal era indicar que _caracter_ não me parece estar correto.

Answer (score 7):

***Caráter*** tem todos os significados do inglês ***character***: letra ou outro sinal gráfico, qualidades psicológicas e morais de uma pessoa, traços distintivos de alguma coisa, etc. Vê por exemplo os dicionários [Aulete digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/car%C3%A1ter), o [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/car%C3%A1cter) ou a [Infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/car%C3%A1ter). Agora, a maioria das pessoas não sabe que *caráter* também significa sinal gráfico, e em vez de caráter usa com este significado os neologismos ***caractere*** no Brasil e ***carater*** em Portugal. Alguns dicionários incluem estes neologismos ([Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/caractere)), outros, como o da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa, não. O Dicionário Houaiss da Língua Portuguesa inclui *caractere* e *caracter* como formas menos corretas de *carácter* (cito na grafia original, anterior ao acordo ortográfico):

> **caracter** *s.m.* INF[ormática] *P[ortugal]* menos cor[recto] que *CARÁCTER*
>   **carácter 1** sinal (letra, número, sinal de pontuação etc.) ou figura usada na escrita **2** (informática) letra do alfabeto, algarismo, sinal de pontuação ou símbolo de qualquer natureza que pode ser introduzido num computador pelo teclado ou por outro dispositivo de entrada, assim como exibido no monitor ou em outro dispositivo de saída > f[orma] menos cor[recta]: *carater, caractere*
>   **caractere** *s.m.* INF[ormática] *B[rasil]* menos cor[recto] que *CARÁCTER*

O Plural de ***caráter*** é muito curioso: ***caracteres*** no Brasil, ***carateres*** ou ***caracteres*** em Portugal. Em Portugal o singular também pode ser ***carácter***.

Agora, se eu me referir, em Portugal, a uma letra ou algarismo por *caráter*, quase toda a gente olha para mim como se eu fosse um marciano, e juram a pé juntos que não pode ser, e perguntam porque é que, já agora, eu não lhe chamo temperamento. E normalmente também pensam que só o plural de *carater* é *carateres*, e que o de *caráter* é *caráteres*. E era isso que eu pensava também até me mostrarem o contrário.

Ao que parece, [a palavra *carater* surgiu na indústria tipográfica](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=745). Nas tipografias é o plural, que é altamente irregular, que é mais usado, e o singular original terá caído no esquecimento. De maneira que depois se formou um singular ‘regular’ retirando o *es* em Portugal e apenas o *s* no Brasil. Nos outros sentidos da palavra *caráter* ter-se-á passado o contrário: o plural é pouco usado, muitas pessoas nunca o ouviram ou leram, e naturalmente quando precisam dele imaginam um plural ‘regular’ de *caráter*. No entanto, o Dicionário Houaiss indica *caracter(e)* apenas como termo informático; em tudo o que se relaciona com tipografia, indica apenas *caráter*.

Comment: O plural da palavra também é [irregular no castelhano](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=caracter), e da mesma forma, mas eu nunca entendi o porquê.

Comment: Então pronto, a culpa é dos espanhóis. Talvez isto faça mais sentido para ti do que para mim: um plural irregular que faz deslocar o acento tónico da sílaba -rá- de carácter para a sílaba -te- de caracteres. Isto acontece provavelmente por ser uma forma de derivação culta, a partir do latim caracter, eris, correspondendo a acentuação em português às vogais longas do latim. (Excerto do link da indústria tipográfica na resposta.)

Comment: Sim, talvez seja por o latim. Vejo que também tem a mesma deslocação do acento tónico o plural de [*épsilon > epsílones*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/%c3%a9psilon). Acho que é porque *épsilon* e palavra esdrúxula no singular, e no caso contrário seria [“sobresdrúxula”](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/09/14/bisesdruxulas/) (ICK! :) no plural. Ou é que *epsilão, epsilões* já existem no português como palavras mais normais?

Comment: Sobresdrúxula sempre é melhor que bisexdrúxula, que nem sei como se pronuncia. Nunca na vida tinha pronunciado ou ouvido ou lido _epsílones_ ou _ipsílones_. Tenho ideia que em Portugal usamos variantes informais: _ípslone_ e _ípslones_. Nós não introduzimos _is_ nos encontros consonantais.

Comment: (Já agora, essas bisesdrúxulas de que falam [no artigo](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/09/14/bisesdruxulas/) são esdrúxulas perfeitamente normais em pt-PT: he·li·cóp·te·ro, etc.)

Comment: Referes-te aquelas em que eles metem um "i" adicional entre duas consoantes: _rítmico, elíptico_? Sim, em Portugal são esdrúxulas normais, nós não metemos ali mais nenhun "i". E sabias desta, que caráter significa letra, algarismo, etc. há séculos? É do caráter, pá! As coisas que uma pessoa não sabe.

Comment: @tchrist Encontrei [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/caracter/14726) uma coisa sobre os plurais de *caráter* e *cadáver*. É algo obscuro para mim, mas tu és capaz de compreender.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Jacinto - Em Portugal, _[cará(c)ter](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/car%C3%A1ter)_ (antes/depois do AO) são formas válidas, sendo _caracter[e]_ formas desaconselhadas. No Brasil, é aceite _[caráter](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?palavra=car%E1ter)_ e _[caractere](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?palavra=caractere)_, embora a segunda pareça ser mais informal. Acho que seria importante referir que _caractere_ é desaconselhado em Portugal, e _caracter_ não é sequer uma grafia válida, mais utilizada oralmente por desconhecedores do singular correto.

Comment: @bandrade Nestas coisas, em vez de dizer que é aconselhável, prefiro dizer explicitamente quem é que aconselha o quê. Acrescentei que o dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa não inclui *cara(c)ter*, e inclui as entradas *caracter, caractere* do Houaiss, definidas como formas menos corretas.

Comment: @Jacinto Agradeço a clarificação! O último parágrafo indica um [link](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=745) onde é referido que "caracter ou caractere [...] é ainda considerada uma forma desaconselhada no português de Portugal"... Sei que o _Houaiss_ indica esta versão como possível, mas (além de ser o único) tem a indicação de menos correto.