# Quando surgiram “caractere” e (a oxítona) “carater”?

Tags: etimologia

***Caractere*** no Brasil e ***carater*** ou ***caracter*** em Portugal designam qualquer sinal usado na escrita, como letra, algarismo, sinal de pontuação, etc.

O que muita gente não sabe é que ***caráter*** (em Portugal também ***carácter***) também tem este significado, para além dos outros mais conhecidos, ‘índolo, qualidades distintivas de pessoa ou coisa’, etc. (ver [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=car%C3%A1ter) e também [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-caracter-e-car%C3%A1ter/1208#1208)). *Caráter* é aliás a palavra original. Desde 1712 que os dicionários de português atribuem a *caráter* todos os significados básicos que a palavra tem hoje, incluindo ‘sinal gráfico’. Estes chegaram até nós já do grego, via latim. Citando o dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa 2001, grafia anterior ao AO90):

> **carácter** *s.m.* (sXIV cf. IVPM) **1** sinal (letra, número, sinal de pontuação etc.) ou figura us. na escrita […] ETIM gr. *kharaktḗr,êros* ‘o que grava, sinal gravado, marca, traço particular do rosto, natureza particular de alguém, marca de estilo’, através do lat. *charācter,ēris*, aproximadamente com os mesmos sentidos e cuja f. permanece na transmissão do cultismo para as línguas modernas de cultura; ver *caracter-*; f.hist. sXIV *carautala*, sXV *carater*, sXV *carautolla* ‘sinal gravado’, sXVII *caracter* ‘cunho, traço característico’

No inglês [(*character*, Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/character), castelhano [(*carácter*, Real Academia Española)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7OboGAc) e francês [(*caractere*, Larousse)](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/caract%C3%A8re/13058?q=caract%C3%A8re#12898) continua a existir uma só palavra com todos os sentidos.

Então uma pergunta é: **quando é que surgiram as variantes *caractere* e *carater/caracter?*** A edição portuguesa de 2003 do dicionário Houaiss (que creio ser na substância igual à edição brasileira de 2001) é o primeiro dicionário que eu conheço que traz *caractere* e *carácter*, que classifica como formas menos corretas de *carácter*. Obviamente as palavras já vinham de antes. Foi ainda antes de 1990, nos meus tempos de estudante, que eu aprendi que *caráter* também significava ‘sinal gráfico’; antes pensava que só *carater* tinha esse significado.

Quanto ao como do surgimento da palavra, diz [Helena Figueira na FLiP (2004)](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/745) que as variantes se formaram a partir do plural. O plural de *caráter* é irregular, *caracteres* (em Portugal também *carateres*). Reproduzo explicação, mas se conseguirem acrescentar pormenores, eu agradeço:

> A palavra *caracter* ou *caractere* tem muitas ocorrências, mas é ainda considerada uma forma desaconselhada no português de Portugal. Qualquer destas formas surgiu por dedução a partir do plural irregular, isto é, nos contextos de *carácter* em que a palavra aparece mais frequentemente no plural (por exemplo, *os caracteres tipográficos, os caracteres de um texto, digitar caracteres*), os falantes fizeram a regularização, por hipercorrecção, do singular a partir do plural irregular, retirando a terminação do plural (*-es* ou *-s*) e mantendo a acentuação tónica do plural (*caract**e**r[es]* ou *caract**e**re[s]*).

---

**Nota para quem for vasculhar textos antigos**. Na escrita, a variante *caractere* distingue-se bem do original por causa do ***e*** final. A variante *carater* distingue-se na fala por causa da sílaba tónica, mas na escrita distingue-se só pelo acento gráfico. Ora o acento gráfico de *caráter* foi introduzido oficialmente só em 1911 em Portugal e 1943 no Brasil. Mesmo em Portugal, muita gente continuou a escrever à antiga depois de 1911. Portanto a forma *carater* ou *caracter*, ou ainda *character*, até às primeiras décadas do século XX, pode representar palavras com acento tónico no ***ra***, a *caráter/carácter* atual. Para tirar dúvidas é preciso ver como é que no mesmo texto aparecem outras palavras: se escritas à moderna—*cadáver, rápido, câmara, útil, ciência*—ou à antiga sem acentos—*cadaver, rapido, camara, util, sciencia/ciencia*, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Penso que tem a ver com a expansão do uso de computadores.

Antes disso tínhamos

- Caráter (singular, paroxítona)
- Caracteres (plural)

Mas o principal uso dessas palavras era no sentido de índole, não de tipos gráficos. E, convenhamos, não é muito usual falar de índoles no plural. Assim, dizíamos que "João tem bom caráter", e que "João e Pedro têm bom caráter" (e não "bons caracteres"). Suponho que os tipógrafos usavam o plural "caracteres"; mas para o leigo, os caracteres eram letras, algarismos, sinais gráficos, não havia muita necessidade de fazer o plural deles como uma única espécie, e não se chamava uma letra ou um algarismo de "caráter".

Mas quando o uso de computadores se popularizou, a necessidade de se referir a letras, algarismos e sinais gráficos como uma só espécie surgiu, e eles passaram a ser chamados "caracteres". Agora, "caracteres" é um plural excepcional, que não segue as regras usuais de formação de plurais da língua portuguesa. Talvez por isso a tendência a chamar uma unidade daquilo que no plural passou a se chamar "caracteres" de "caracter". Ou talvez seja a estranheza de usar a palavra "caráter" (que a maioria dos falantes da língua sempre teve como um sinônimo aproximado de "índole") para designar algo tão diferente. Ou uma combinação das duas coisas.

Comment: As pessoas não associam o caráter da letra a sua forma. Então, o mais provável seja a adoção da forma em inglês character transformada em caractere.

Comment: Sim, provavelmente se não fores leitor do Júlio Dinis, não encontrarás frequentemente frases como [Maurício possuía um d'esses caracteres faceis de dominar](https://books.google.pt/books?id=HOUFAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA149&dq=%22caracteres+faceis+de+dominar%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCz8bBks3SAhVGbhQKHfdqDfMQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22caracteres%20faceis%20de%20dominar%22&f=false).

Comment: Possivelmente os computadores contribuíram para popularizar *carater* e *caractere*, mas o meu palpite é que as palavras tenha surgido ainda antes; talvez entre tipógrafos, talvez até por brincadeira--já ouvi pessoal a mudar deliberadamente o acento tónico de palvras só por brincadeira. Mas isto são só palpites. Eu que eu quero mesmo são exemplos de uso com datas.

Comment: @Jacinto - Tem de ter sido pós-1980, que é quando começa a popularização do uso de computadores pessoais, mas data exata vai ser difícil, porque para o Google *carácter* e *caracter* são a mesma coisa...

Comment: @Jacinto - Difícil, mas a gente dá um jeito. A mais antiga entrada para "caractere" que consigo encontrar é de 4 de novembro de 1989, no saite "Canivete Suíço do Shell, de Aurélio Marinho Jargas (http://aurelio.net/shell/canivete/). Mas há uma contradição na data, pois o Google diz que é de 1989, mas o próprio Canivete Suíço diz "desde 2003".

Comment: @Jacinto - Já para "caracter", o mais antigo que encontro é de 1994, no saite da ABNT (!?) (http://www.dca.ufrn.br/~acari/Desenho%20Mecanico/Temas%20para%20semin%E1rios/NBR8402.pdf), e aí a data do Google bate com a data interna do documento (MAR 1994). Trata-se da NBR 8402, portanto documento oficial da ABNT (Associação Brasileira de Normas Técnicas). A menos que se trate de erro de digitação, portanto, a forma "caracter", no sentido de "caráter tipográfico", parece ter curso normativo no Brasil desde pelo menos 1994.

Comment: @Jacinto Como a natureza das coisas é de que a língua oficial, como os maridos traídos, é a última a reconhecer a situação factual, é de crer que "caracter" já vinha circulando menos formalmente havia algum tempo em 1994. Mas o Google não mostra nada anterior a isso. Por outro lado, claro, o Google só mostra o que está na internet.

Comment: Não me digas que não conheces a opção "livros" ou "books" na pesquisa do Google? Tens lá livros digitalizados desde o tempo dos Afonsinhos.