# Taxonomia ou taxinomia?

Tags: ortografia

Certo é que o dicionário da Porto Editora tem os dois verbetes, mas o primeiro reencaminha meramente para o segundo. Assim pergunto:

- é mais correto grafar taxonomia ou [taxinomia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/taxinomia)?
- a que se deve esta dupla grafia?

Por exemplo, [neste artigo](http://visao.sapo.pt/opiniao/ricardo-araujo-pereira/2019-07-12-Chaticias) o autor Ricardo Araújo Pereira grafa taxinomia, mas a Wikipédia tem entrada apenas para [taxonomia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomia).

Comment: Então, tu fazes a pergunta e depois nunca mais apareces para ver as respostas que te dão?

Comment: @Jacinto não sei porquê mas não tinha recebido qualquer notificação de resposta.

Comment: Pois, eu vi que tu não vinhas cá basicamente desde que fizeste a pergunta, e pensei que tivesse acontecido uma coisa desse tipo, ou que a notificação tivesse ficado "enterrado" no meio de muitas outras.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Taxonomia*** e ***taxinomia*** estão ambas corretas: vêm em todos os dicionários, e nenhum levanta objeções a qualquer uma das variantes. O Houaiss diz quando tem algo contra uma palavra. Vê por exemplo o caso de *carater* e *caractere*, que o Houaiss diz serem formas menos corretas que *caráter* (vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-caracter-e-car%C3%A1ter/1208#1208)). Alguns dicionários registam também *taxionomia*, que o Houaiss diz ser forma a evitar.

A  [Wikipédia em franês (*Taxonomie*)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomie) explica tudo o que se possa desejar saber acerca da origem das vária versões. Foi tudo culpa do botânico suíço  Augustin Pyrame de Candolle , que em 1813 cunhou *taxonomie*; segundo explicou mais tarde, a partir do grego *taxeôs*, genitivo de *taxis* ’classificação, ordenação’ e *nomos*  ’lei, regra’, suprimindo o **e** para encurtar a palavra. Em 1819 arrependeu-se e admitiu que *taxéonomie* seria mais correto. Em 1864 [este dicionário francês](https://books.google.pt/books?id=P1Ke2G8mSb8C&pg=PA1175&dq=%22et%20mieux%20taxinomie%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDu9ei377jAhXZ8uAKHVu3AVAQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=%22et%20mieux%20taxinomie%22&f=false) propôs *taxinomie*, formado a partir do nominativo *taxis*, como melhor que *taxonomie*. Em 1872 o célebre [Littré](https://books.google.pt/books?id=gDcejhliMl8C&pg=PA2158&dq=%22taxinomie%20ta-ksi-no-mie%20ou%20taxionomie%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8ivzt4L7jAhUQ1eAKHWcfC3EQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=%22taxinomie%20ta-ksi-no-mie%20ou%20taxionomie%22&f=false) condenou *taxonomie* e aconselhou *taxinomie* ou *taxionomie*. *Taxionomie* não pegou; as outras duas mantêm-se em uso, ultimamente com vantagem para *taxinomies* ([Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=taxonomie%2Ctaxinomie%2Ctaxionomie&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctaxonomie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctaxinomie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctaxionomie%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctaxonomie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctaxinomie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctaxionomie%3B%2Cc0)). Segundo o dicionário Houaiss (verbetes *tax(i/o)-* e *taxonomia*), a forma *taxionomie* foi proscrita por poder ser confundida com a formação a partir de *taxis* e *onoma* ’nome’.

Os anglófonos, pragmáticos, adotaram a forma original francesa, e ficaram-se pelo [*taxonomy* (Etymoline)](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=taxonomy). Mas nós tínhamos de adotar as formas todas. O Houaiss desaconselha *taxionomia*, mas o dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa não, e inclusivamente no verbetes *taxonomia* e *taxinomia* simplesmente remete para *taxionomia*.

Voltando à questão de qual é a forma mais correta ou se há uma que é mais correta, está bem de ver que a resposta vai depender do critério de cada um. Quem der muita importância à derivação regular do grego, vai preferir *taxinomia* ou *taxionomia*; mas poderá não querer esta última por causa do argumento do Houaiss. Quem privilegiar a antiguidade, preferirá *taxonomia*. Tudo começou com *taxonomie* no francês, e *taxonomia* é também a que aprece mais cedo em português. Encontra-se já em 1841 ([Revista Litteraria](https://books.google.pt/books?id=XFCK_o4BtOcC&pg=PA172&dq=taxonomia&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqyoKEt7_jAhUICRoKHS_iC844FBDoAQg8MAM#v=onepage&q=taxonomia&f=false), vol. 7, Porto e [António Benevides, *Diccionario de glossologia botanica*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=PLA26P8URNIC&q=taxonomia&dq=taxonomia&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqyoKEt7_jAhUICRoKHS_iC844FBDoAQgvMAE)), e vem no  no dicionário de Moraes Silva de 1858; *taxionomia*, encontrei em 1869 ([O Auxiliador da Industria Nacional, Rio de Janeiro](https://books.google.pt/books?id=HcozAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA178&dq=taxionomia&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBpr3YuL_jAhWUQkEAHV1QBwAQ6AEIPzAD#v=onepage&q=taxionomia&f=false)) e vem, tal como *taxinomia*, no dicionário de Domingos Vieira de 1874.

Comment: Um verdadeiro serviço público. Obrigado Jacinto