# Qual o nome, em português brasileiro, para o elemento químico At (Z=85)?

Tags: português-brasileiro, ortografia

Procurando pela web  entrei três diferentes nomes em português para o elemento químico <sub>85</sub>At ([Astatine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astatine), em inglês). 
Qual a forma correta (aceita), em português brasileiro, para o nome desse elemento químico: *Ástato*, *Astato* ou *Astatínio*?

Comment: É possível encontrar [Ástato](https://pessoas.iq.ufrj.br/~faria/Tabela_633.pdf) e [Astato](http://www.cesadufs.com.br/ORBI/public/uploadCatalago/13414510012017Quimica_Inorganica_II_Aula_8.pdf) nos artigos escritos por alunos dos cursos de química. Entretanto, para [Romeu C. Rocha-Filho](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=S0100-40421999000500022&script=sci_arttext&tlng=pt) e [Aécio Pereira Chagas](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=S0100-40421999000500022&script=sci_arttext&tlng=pt), o correto é *astato*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os dicionários, brasileiros e potugueses, são unânimes: ***astatínio*** ou ***ástato***. Estes são os nomes que encontras no [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/%C3%A1stato/), [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/%C3%A1stato), [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/astat%C3%ADnio), dicionário Houaiss e ainda na [Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario). Cito o Houaiss (desenvolvendo algumas abreviações):

> **astatínio** *s.m.* (*1947*) QUÍM elemento químico artificial de número atómico 85 da família dos halogéneos (simb.: *At*) […] ʘ ETIM inglês *astatine* (1947) ’idem’ (< grego *ástatos,os,on* ’instável, não fixo, incerto’) + sufixo *-ine* (português *-ino*/*-ina*), acrescido na adaptação ao português, de um segundo sufixo *-io*, dominante modernamente nos nomes dos elementos químicos; o nome foi criado em 1947 por D.R. Carson e adoptado oficialmente em 1949; ver *astat-* ʘ Sinónimo/variante ástato.
>
> **ástato** *s.m.* (1712 cf. RB) **1** *antigo* soldado armado com lança **2** QUÍM mesmo que ASTATÍNIO ʘ ETIM grego *ástatos,os,on* ’instável, não fixo, incerto’; ver *astat-* f.hist. 1712 *astato*, 1712 *hastato*.

Naturalmente, o *ástato* de 1712 referia-se ao soldado, e escrevia-se sem acento porque os acentos em palavras como *ástato, música* ou *política* tornaram-se norma só com as reformas ortográficas do princípio do século XX (1911 em Portugal, 1943 no Brasil).

[Romeu C. Rocha-Filho e Aécio Pereira Chagas](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=S0100-40421999000500022&script=sci_arttext&tlng=pt), referido no comentário acima, recomendam a paroxítona *astato* em vez da proparoxítona *ástato*, aparentemente por ignorarem que a palavra é uma adaptação da proparoxítona grega *ástatos*.

Comment: *Ástato* e *Astatínio* soam tão estranho. Nunca ouvi ninguém usar essas formas.

Comment: @GRSousaJr, lol, e eu nem sabia que esse elemento químico existia. O que é que ouves? *Astato*?

Comment: Isso mesmo! *Astato* é nome usado (pelo menos aqui no Brasil) para o elemento 85, da mesma família do cloro (Z=17, Cl, aquele do sal de cozinha), esse sim bem mais conhecido.

Comment: @GRSousaJr, não faço ideia como é em Portugal; não sou químico. *Ástato* e *astatínio* é o que vem nos dicionários agora. Não quer dizer que daqui a uns anos, se o pessoal continuar a usar *astato*, os dicionários não mudem. Pode acontecer o que aconteceu com *caráter* e *caracter(e)*. Vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-caracter-e-car%C3%A1ter/1208#1208)

Comment: Encontrei [essa referência](https://www.spq.pt/magazines/BSPQuimica/649/article/30001596/pdf), da Sociedade Portuguesa de Química, com recomendações para os nomes desse e de outros elementos químicos, nas variantes europeia e brasileira.

Comment: @GRSousaJr, interessante. Portanto eles recomendam simplesmente *ástato*, derivado diretamente do grego, e não o *astatínio*, derivado via inglês.

Comment: (Dicionários **potugueses** -> portugueses.)